# Logical error in query formation without using DISTINCT in query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

> Find the makers of the PCs that have speed not less than 450MHz. Result set: Maker.

My Query -

```
SELECT maker FROM product
WHERE model IN ( SELECT model FROM pc WHERE speed > 450 ) AND type = 'PC'
```

Output -

[image: output]

however i tried by adding `DISTINCT` in my query and its giving the desired output, but there is some logical error in my query as it is not passing the system.

DB Schema -

[image: schema]

```
SELECT * FROM product --
```

[image: query1]

```
SELECT * FROM pc  --
```

[image: query2]

Comment: this is a problem from `SQL_EX.RU`

Comment: @JW.  yup sure, but this is not my question :) I tried and I failed, with what i failed I mentioned it :)

Comment: You forgot to say what "logical error" you get in your `DISTINCT` query and what exactly you mean by "not passing the system".

Comment: @JW. Please find my below comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `JOIN`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT b.maker
FROM    PC a
        INNER JOIN Product b
           ON a.model = b.model
WHERE   speed >= 450
```

Comment: bro I already tried DISTINCT :( and this is what i am getting with your query -  Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed test on second, checking database.
* Wrong number of records (less by 2)

Comment: yeah thx ..last thing I should have try for this..however the exercise is a basic so I thought not to use joins at the preliminary stage and trying with the other way and stuck :(

Comment: lol one more VERY BASIC ..which is also letting me to pass -- SELECT DISTINCT a.maker
FROM Product a, PC b
WHERE a.model=b.model and b.speed > =450

Comment: Please add this one as in your answer as well for future reference :)

Comment: @swapnesh the query `SELECT DISTINCT a.maker FROM Product a, PC b WHERE a.model=b.model and b.speed > =450` is an old syntax type of join.

Comment: ok got ur point ..thx a ton ..it is a very good tutorial to follow..pretty good exercises thr ..just started playing with that and find it a good place..anyway thx a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

Or simply this too works,

```
Select distinct Product.maker from Product, PC
where Product.model = PC.model
and PC.speed >= 450
```